# How to get caller name inside pytest fixture?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, inspect

Assume we have:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    print('All set up!')
    return True

def foo(setup):
    print('I am using a fixture to set things up')
    setup_done=setup
```

I'm looking for a way to get to know caller function name (in this case: foo) from within setup fixture.

So far I have tried:

```py
import inspect

@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    daddy_function_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    print(daddy_function_name)

    print('All set up!')
    return True
```

But what gets printed is: `call_fixture_func`

How do I get `foo` from printing `daddy_function_name`?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting further up in the stack?

Comment: I have looked over everything that inspect.stack() returned and couldn't find any useful information on that matter (or didn't know what I was looking for).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [the built-in `request` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#request) in your own fixture:

> The `request` fixture is a special fixture providing information of the requesting test function.

[Its `node` attribute](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.FixtureRequest.node) is the

> Underlying collection node (depends on current request scope).

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def setup(request):
    return request.node.name


def test_foo(setup):
    assert setup == "test_foo"
```